# How to increase Angular's (2+) change detection performance?

Tags: angular, architecture

I have been developing Angular applications for more than 8 months. I am overwhelmed by Angular 2+ architecture (compared to Angular JS). I read few articles/ guidelines about the best practices and all, but none of them doesn't address about improving the performance in change detection.

Could anyone please advise me on this?

Comment: you can skip entire subtrees for change-detection using the "OnPush" change detection strategy and using immutable objects.  For example, if you know that the only way a component can change (or its sub components) is when its input changes, then you can use the "OnPush" strategy on certain components to improve performance.

Comment: @pixelbits It orders Angular to depend only on its @inputs(). Doesn't it?

Comment: @pixelbits is posted correct approach, for reference how it's work please click on this link https://medium.com/@bencabanes/angular-change-detection-strategy-an-introduction-819aaa7204e7

Comment: @KushanRandima it also depends on output

Comment: Tell us the scenario where you have performance problems. The question is not concrete enough.

Comment: Actually, I do not have performance issues in the current project which is being developed using Angular 5. When I was working with Angular JS in my last project I was experiencing a slowness in the deployed application after a couple of hours when users start using it. After the investigations, I found that there were a lot of memory leaks and a few other data binding issues. I really want to stick to best practices this time and avoid any issues when the application get expanding